# Angular: Авторизация на сайте

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, servlet

Имеется типичная форма логина/пароля. Отправка формы по submit перехватывается в angular, потом отправляется ajax запрос на сервер и, если получен статус ОК, делаю window.location.replace(...) т.е. перегружаю страницу на нужный мне адрес и пользователь на нее попадает уже залогиненный. Насколько это правильно и безопасно, или нужно все-таки  submit прямо на сервер посылать?

Comment: это можно сделать и редиректор  с сервера.

Answer (score 1):

XHR не редиректится, т.е. при использовании Angular, переадресация возможна только на клиенте. Таким образом этот код будет храниться в JS, что допускает его просмотр и модификацию. Что можно с этим сделать, уже другой вопрос - может и ничего.
Если вы используете обычный сабмит, переадресацию для login success / failure можно делать на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически можно и так. Важно понимать как работает бэк в чати токенов кукисов и т.п. Исходя из этого уже, после получения ответа заносить данные на клиенте и обновлять страницу.

Но это костыльный метод. Если вы не хотите полностью использовать ангуляр, то используйте только валидацию и прочие локальные плюшки, а отправку уже делайте через сервер.

Лучшим же вариантом будет полностью разделить на два приложения - клиент, сервер и настроить общение через апишку с обменом/проверкой токенов.

Одно время тоже пытался смягчить переход постепенным внедрением ангуляра, больше времени потратил.